# How to create a list of dicts in this way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I tried to make a list of dicts in the method below, hoping that I could start creating my list of dicts by index number. But the error is of course "Name dogdict is not defined."

How would I declare `dogdict` to allow this to run smoothly?

```
import random

slist=['big','medium','small']

for i in range(10):
    dogdict[i]['name']=random.randint(1,100)
    dogdict[i]['size']=random.choice(slist)

print("it's dog time... a list of dict")
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    print(dogdict[i])
```

Comment: There is no simple way to declare `dogdict` to make this work. You can't assign into an empty list by index.

Comment: thanks much. your sentence "You can't assign into an empty list by index" is of course the basic lesson here. I guess I grew up using arrays and I kept trying to force a List to be the same as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put items into a container that is non existent. You first have to initialize, then you can make *appends* to add new items at the **tail** of the container:

```
import random

slist = ['big','medium','small']

dogdict = []          # initialize list
for _ in range(10):   # index is never used
    d = {}            # initialize dict
    d['name'] = random.randint(1,100)
    d['size'] = random.choice(slist)
    dogdict.append(d)
```

Of course, there are more elegant ways of doing this. You could use a *list comprehension* to build the dictionaries which will be placed in the resulting list:

```
doglist = [{'name': random.randint(1,100), 'size': random.choice(slist)} 
                                                      for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: thank you much, crystal clear! I knew that the append method was out there calling me, but I kept thinking that I could do it this more mechanistic way. and the comprehension really helps me too. giant thanks

Comment: and I never knew that I could use underscore when the index of a for loop would not be useful. thx